# how to upgrade already installed apache2 on debian (lenny)

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, apt, debian-lenny

I have an debian lenny box up and running with apache2 2.11.6 (this was testing stream some month agotesting some)

Now on testing stream is 2.12.1 I want to upgrade my apache2, but **not** the other software on this machine.
So I think:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

.. is not an option.

How can I upgrade only single packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: This will try to upgrade to latest version

Comment: Are you sure? I think it will remove my testing version and install the stable (2.10.9)?

Comment: Only if your version is older than what's there.  If you need a newer version, you'll need to build it, or find existing packages built for Lenny.

Comment: Run the command and see what packages will be removed, installed and upgraded... that way you can be sure your package won't be touched.  If it is, then there's some more magic you'll need to do.  If your package doesn't show here, I think it would be safe to hit "Y" to go ahead and upgrade Apache2.

Comment: You are right, however now there is no php as module anymore, however this is another problem.. thanx for helping!

Answer (score 4):

1. add a line for testing to your /etc/apt/sources.list.

   e.g. if you have the following sources.list already

   ```
   deb http://your.favourite.mirror/debian/ stable main non-free contrib
   ```

   then yank and paste it and change the copy to

   ```
   deb http://your.favourite.mirror/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
   ```
2. edit or create /etc/apt/preferences to assign Pinning priorities, like so

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=testing
   Pin-Priority: 100

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=stable
   Pin-Priority: 500
   ```
3. run "apt-get update"
4. install apache2 from testing (along with all required dependancies) with:

   ```
   apt-get -t testing install apache2
   ```

from now on, when you run apt-get upgrade or apt-get install it will install packages from stable by default but you can override that at any time with "-t testing" to install specific packages (or even a full upgrade) from testing.

you can do the same thing with "unstable" too.  just add it with a lower priority than testing.

personally, i would use unstable *instead of* testing.  in my experience, testing is often more broken than unstable because there are often very long delays in getting crucial updates to migrate from unstable to testing - all it takes is one new (or duplicate) bug to be reported or a slightly new revision to be uploaded to unstable, and the automatic migration of a package from unstable to testing will be delayed for another week or two or more...which is more than enough time for yet another bug report or updated package to be uploaded to unstable to reset the delay all over again.

Comment: Ditto for "deb ... testing main..."!

Answer (score 0):

```
man dpkg
```

but what about dependencies ?

Comment: I have installed a lot of other stuff.. I just want to upgrade apache2 (and its dependencies, but not (eg) mysql, perl, python ...etc..)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) apt will try to resolve dependencies from testing if you use this format:

```
apt-get -t testing install package
```

But, if you use this other format, it will resolve dependencies from stable:

```
apt-get install package/testing
```