# Do I need to update some of my Debian Squeeze software?

Tags: debian-squeeze, update, upgrade

I have installed Debian 6, and LAMP stack from squeeze repository (default).

After upgrading Apache 2.2.16 from unstable repository to 2.2.22, thanks to this post -  [how to upgrade already installed apache2 on debian (lenny)](https://serverfault.com/questions/58724/how-to-upgrade-already-installed-apache2-on-debian-lenny)

I'm thinking to upgrade all other software packages that I've previously installd from squeeze repository. Should I upgrade them to the ones from unstable repository? Should I upgrade all of them or just selected ones?
Here's the list:

```
* arno-iptables-firewall    1.9.2.k-4 >> 2.0.1.c-1
* bind9                     1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze6 >> 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4.2
* php-apc                   3.1.3p1-2 >> 3.1.13-1
* fail2ban                  0.8.4-3+squeeze1 >> 0.8.6-3
* exim4                     4.72-6+squeeze2 >> 4.80-4
* altermime                 0.3.10-4 >> 0.3.10-7
* rrdtool                   1.4.3-1 >> 1.4.7-2
* vsftpd                    2.3.2-3+squeeze2 >> 3.0.0-4
```

Also I would like to ask how to upgrade 5.3.3 >> 5.3.16, unstable repository has 5.4.x versions only, I don't think I'm ready to move from 5.3 to 5.4 yet.

Actually I'm a newbie in Linux, and after Windows experience I have a paranoidal idea to update software to the latest release.

I'd be glad for any suggestions and recommendations!

Thank you very much!

Comment: I've discovered this resource: _https://launchpad.net/debian/+source//+changelog

I think I should stick to this resource to find out news about software I use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just playing with the server, then go ahead and update. If it breaks you have the chance to learn how to fix it, and may solve some lovely dependency issues.

If you are planning something more serious, stick with the stable version.

my 2 cents

Comment: Thank's a lot! Actually I'm preparing production server! :)